# Max length for a dynamic array in Delphi 64?

Tags: delphi

My current question is related to [Max length for a dynamic array in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985015/max-length-for-a-dynamic-array-in-delphi). That question was asked in 2009 when the 64 bit compiler was not available. I am preparing migration to Delphi XE2 (or whatever version is available for purchase not) or to Lazarus because I need 64 bit support.

I would like to know what changed (related to dynamic array max length) in Delphi 64bit. Can I create bigger arrays now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dynamic array lengths are, in modern Delphi, `NativeInt`.

This means that dynamic arrays are limited in theory to 32 bit lengths in 32 bit code, and 64 bit length in 64 bit code. Of course, practical considerations mean that the limits are somewhat lower. However it is possible to allocate dynamic arrays with more than 2<sup>32</sup> elements in 64 bit code.

On the other hand, strings are subject to a 32 bit limit on their length for all architectures. As I understand it the reasoning is that strings are simply not expected to hold such large amounts of text. And many of the text support library functions that strings rely on use 32 bit lengths. Whereas arrays are used for more general purpose computing and a 32 bit limit would greatly reduce their utility under 64 bits.

Comment: Thanks Davis. Very prompt answer as usual.

Comment: "As I understand it the reasoning is that strings are simply not expected to hold such large amounts of text." It's a violation of the "0,1,infinity" rule though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule  I've seen biology programs processing genetic sequences that find it very useful to use a string greater than 2GB.

Comment: @alcalde-Indeed. I have a 32GB RAM PC and still need a RAM upgrade to process all data.

Comment: @alcalde those are not strings. They are arrays.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What aren't strings?

Comment: @alcalde genetic sequences

Comment: Genetic sequences are hold in ASCII strings (well you can hold them also in Unicode if you want to waste some RAM). They are characters A,C,G,T for DNA nucleotides and other alphabetic characters for ambiguous bases and proteins. Also - for Gap.

Comment: @Altar They aren't strings. It's just a neat notation for humans to read them. You need 2 bits to encode ACGT. Wasteful to use 8 bits when 2 suffice.

Comment: 1. I never said that. The DNA is a molecule not a computer string:) What I said is that you need more the 4 chars (ACGT) to represent a DNA sequence or protein. Please take a look at the UIPAC code and you will see. 2. Encoding DNA on a number of bits lower than 8 will make the things terribly slow. In many cases you need to compare or to assemble two looooong sequences. In this case it is better to keep the data unpacked (as byte or ANSI string).

Comment: Can see the point re perf. But then use byte array rather than string.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Altar beat me to it. In the one program I took a look at the input file was simply one giant string of A,C,G,T. People working on programs like this are what they term "non-programmer programmers": they're turning to programming to solve a problem, not create software to sell. Since genetic code to them is one giant string, they'd like to treat it as one in a program. Correct me if I'm wrong but things like Posex() and Regex aren't going to work on arrays of byte (biologists are often searching for sequences or data in-between sequences in progs like this).

Comment: @alcalde - Yes, the files will be easy to compress but I never heard somebody keeping the DNA data compressed (as 2bits per char). The NCBI database is estimated to reach 12000 terabytes in the next two years and they still work in ASCII format. MAYBE the servers keep internally the data compressed but I highly doubt about it because then every time you search the database it needs to be unpacked. Anyway, the end user is working with large (even 10-20GB) ASCII files.

Comment: Minor attention to detail, is the max string length 2^32 minus null character byte? and any other redundant data stored in the string that does not count? For short strings that might be the length byte stored in the structure?  But, over all it's so close to 2^32 that it's likely not even worth calculating. If someone wanted to absolutely fill the string to the max length possible, they would need to know this exact detail. The length of an ansistring is stored in a record field, outside the string, AFAIR? But a null char is stored in the string? or, no null char, as it is not a C like pchar?